# Migration Xcode 4.6 to 5 causes popover view controllers height increase

Tags: height, ios7, uitableview, xcode5

I just made a migration of my storyboard.

All TableViewControllers height increase by XXpx at each time i change a property in the tableViewController (Size, Orientation, Status Bar, Top bar, Bottom Bar)

No matter which property i set, height always increase, and i have to change it manually.

I use no Auto Layout
When i click on arrow to increase or decrease height, height always increase by XX px !!

---

**Ex before migration**

TableViewController height : 69px

Top Bar, Bottom bar : NO

TableViewControllerCell heigth : 69px

**Ex After migration**

TableViewController height : 89px

Top Bar, Bottom bar : NO

TableViewControllerCell heigth : 69px

---

If i try to put manually "69" in tableviewcontroller height, it automatically set it à 89px
I have to set "49px" to finally get 69px.

And at each time i change a property (Orientation for example), height of my tableViewController increase by 20px...

Somebody has an idea?
Thanks a lot

Edit : This is an Xcode bug. I downloaded the version 5.0.1, corrected the size of my windows and all of them didn't grow up.
Thanks for your help

Comment: It is problem due to AutoLayout, checkout the autolayout constraints in older version and after adding it in Xcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an Xcode bug. I downloaded the version 5.0.1, corrected the size of my windows and all of them didn't grow up. Thanks for paying attention to this bug

Answer (score 0):

In my last proyect I am using nib files, but I had the same problem. Try this in every viewDidLoad methods:

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0")) {
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone; 
}
```

Put this in your proyect prefix:

```
#define IsIPad (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#define IsRetina [[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)] == YES && [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.00
#define isIphone5 ([[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height == 568)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_EQUAL_TO(v) ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedSame)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN(v) ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedDescending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v) ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(v) ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v) ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedDescending)
```